# Select field of field using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, field

does facebook support field of filed for graph api?

For example,
    https://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/friends/?fields=events

will give all friends and their events.
Can I also control which field i want in the events by doing something like

```
<https://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/friends/?fields=events,events__updated_time>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly through the Graph API, however the best thing to do with more complex queries is to look into [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/). In your specific example, you can do something like this:

`SELECT eid, update_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))`

You can run this against the Graph API by doing:

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT eid, update_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))`

Test this using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)